# Как вкл/выкл отслеживание события если сработало другое?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот мой пример, как отменить mouseover если кнопку мыши отпустили?

```js
var mouseOverEventListener;
$('#pixel_canvas').mousedown(function () {
  mouseOverEventListener = $('#pixel_canvas').on('mouseover', 'td', function () {
    $( this ).css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});

$('#pixel_canvas').mouseup(function () {
  $('#pixel_canvas').off('mouseover', mouseOverEventListener)
});
```

```css
tr {
    height: 15px;
}

td {
    width: 15px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd),
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="pixel_canvas">

    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: @Даниил, как отключить mouseover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Event preventDefault"** - Метод объекта  позволяет предотвратить выполнение стандартного действия.

**Mousedown** - Событие срабатывает, когда кнопка нажата над элементом.

**Mouseup** - Событие срабатывает, когда кнопка мыши отпущена над элементом.

**Mouseover** - Событие срабатывает, когда мышь появилась над элементом.

**Off** - Удаляет обработчики событий, назначенные методом ".on"

```js
 $('#pixel_canvas').mousedown(
    function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
        $('#pixel_canvas').on('mouseover', 'td', function () {
          $( this ).css('background-color', 'red');
        });           
    }).mouseup(function(){ 
      $('#pixel_canvas').off('mouseover' )

});
```

```css
tr {
    height: 15px;
}

td {
    width: 15px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd),
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="pixel_canvas">

    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Подскажите, почему иногда появлеятся cursor в виде not-allowed и даже после того как отпустить кнопку mouseover все равно работает, до следующего нажатия.

Comment: А что это за событие "Перетаскивание при клике" которые вы выключаете, первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь?

Comment: @E_K обновил ответ, надеюсь так будет яснее.

Answer (score 0):

```
Вам надо сделать, что то вроде
`$('#pixel_canvas').mousedown(function () {
  $('#pixel_canvas').on('mouseover', 'td', function () {
    $( this ).css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});
$('#pixel_canvas').mouseup(function () { // код }
`
```

И в mouseup уже реализовать логику удаление эвента методом .off() https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: как отключить mouseover при mouseup?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте .off метод jquery для отключения слушателя от события:

```js
var mouseOverEventListener;
$('#pixel_canvas').mousedown(function () {
  mouseOverEventListener = $('#pixel_canvas').on('mouseover', 'td', function () {
    $( this ).css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});

$('#pixel_canvas').mouseup(function () {
  $('#pixel_canvas').off('mouseover', mouseOverEventListener)
}
```